# What is the difference between LDADD and LIBADD?

Tags: c++, automake, libtool

I'm trying to setup an automake project that uses a mix of libtool libraries and exectuables, and I'm having a hard time grokking the automake documentation, esp. as relates to telling the compiler to link against.

So can someone explain the differences between `LDADD` and `LIBADD`?

Things like:

- when is one used over the other,
- which one takes `-lname_of_library` style values vs. direct filenames,
  etc.

Whenever I try to read the relevant documentation, it seems like it assumes that I know things that I don't.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the [`LIBADD`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html#index-maude_005fLIBADD-1) primary for libraries, and [`LDADD`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html#index-maude_005fLDADD-1) for executables. If you were building a libtool library `libfoo.la`, that depended on another library `libbar.la`, you would use:

```
libfoo_la_LIBADD = libbar.la
```

If you had other non-libtool libraries, you would also add these with `-L` and `-l` options:

```
libfoo_la_LIBADD = libbar.la -L/opt/local/lib -lpng
```

Typically, you would use the configure script to find these extra libraries, and use `AC_SUBST` to pass them with:

```
libfoo_la_LIBADD = libbar.la $(EXTRA_FOO_LIBS)
```

For a program, just use `LDADD` :

```
myprog_LDADD = libfoo.la # links libfoo, libbar, and libpng to myprog.
```

Sometimes the boundaries are a bit vague. `$(EXTRA_FOO_LIBS)` could have been added to `myprog_LDADD`. Adding dependencies to a libtool (`.la`) library, and using `libtool` do all the platform-specific linker magic, is usually the best approach. It keeps all the linker metadata in the one place.

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned in one of the books, `LDADD` is ADDitional linker(LD) items - i.e. items that are added when performing linking. This would be, for example, when producing programs. `LDADD` can specify:

- libtool files e.g. `lib/libfudge.la`
- libraries e.g. `-lm`, or
- full paths to libraries e.g. `/lib/libmagicalwonderland.a`
- link flags & libraries e.g. `-L/opt/lib -lmagical`

They are in order of preference - Using the last two is just *asking* for trouble as they're pointing at things that may or may not be present.

`LIBADD` is to specify ADDitional LIBraries to use. This is used when building a library to specify that additional libraries are needed in order to build or make use of the library. You'll see it specified as something like `libfred_la_LIBADD =`. It can be used to specify libtool libraries, or system libraries and will place these libraries into the resulting libtool `.la` for the library so when it comes to linking against the library you get all the appropriate libraries brought along.

You should only specify libraries to link, so, for example, my library `libfred.la` depends on some math routines i.e. it depends on `libm`. When I'm specifying the *additional libraries* for the library, I state:

```
libfred_la_LIBADD = -lm
```

This dependency is encoded when I build the library, and gets passed on to consumers of the library as well.

The rule of thumb is:

- LIBADD for things that are being added *to a library*
- LDADD for things that are being added *to a program*

Comment: Which books do you mean?